# client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myapp.wsgi

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am getting this error while setting up my server for flask and apache on debian.
I've read through similar errors and I have changed all

```
order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

to

```
Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

but still the same error. I've also checked running my applciation with current user (not root) in /var/www and it worked fine and also used a browser on localhost and everything is fine.

I finally succeeded in solving problem by changing

```
  /etc/apache2/sites-available/ispconfig.conf
```

and commenting out

```
deny from all
```

for

```
<Directory />
```

but obviously I dont like this solution. It seems I am giving apache permission to root folder.
Any suggestions what is wrong?!
could it be for my python installation or.... I did not use any virtualenv as most tutorials suggested.

Also can I make more debug info available from apache?! I am using LogLevel debug, but I still don't see any more information!
How hard is it for apache to tell me what file has wrong permission!!!